# can't resolve 'ph.archive.ubuntu.com'

Tags: apt, sudo, cmake

I am trying to install `cmake` and it said try running `sudo apt-get install cmake`. Then I entered `Y` but after a while the terminal displayed `can't resolve 'ph.archive.ubuntu.com'`. Is there really an instance when a server goes down/offline?

Comment: What does `dig ph.archive.ubuntu.com` say?

Answer (score 1):

If your system can't *resolve*, that is a DNS problem (or, in some cases but not in that case, in /etc/hosts file). Here, I tried to resolve ph.archive.ubuntu.com, and I have got:

```
$ host ph.archive.ubuntu.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Probably, the Canonical's DNS servers have some issue (or simply it dropped this subdomain for some reason).